# Estrange behavior while using the mysql IN and not In operator

Tags: mysql

I have a table A with 100 rows and another with 200 rows. If I do:

```
select A.keya 
from A 
where A.keya not in (Select B.keyb from B)
```

I get 0 results. Then I run

```
select A.keya 
from A 
where A.keya in (Select B.keyb from B)
```

and I get 50 results

am I missing something with the IN operator?. Keya and keyb are Varchar fields.

shouldn't the first query return 150 entries?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation I can imagine here is that 50 of the 100 values in your `A` table are `NULL`.  For `NULL` values, *both* of the following two expressions would always fail:

```
WHERE NULL NOT IN (SELECT keyb FROM B)
WHERE NULL IN (SELECT keyb FROM B)
```

So, if 50 `keya` values match, then your second query results would be expected.  But for the first query, the 50 matching values would then fail, *and* the `NULL` values would also appear to fail.

Comment: keya and keyb are not null :-(

Comment: Then you need to make your question _reproducible_ by showing us some data which we can test on our own.  Better yet, setup a demo and paste the link in your question.  At this point, I would even doubt your analysis of what data you think you currently have.

Comment: u were right.... Somehow I found a row, JUST ONE ROW, with a null value for keyb... all failed then!

Comment: I think I get it now.  That `NULL` value was causing everything compared against the subquery to fail.

Answer (score 1):

`not in` is not opposite to `in`.

`select a.keya from a where a.keya not in ('a', 'b')`

is the same as

`select a.keya from a where a.keya != 'a' and a.keya !='b'`

See [NULL compare: UNKNOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Effect_of_Null_and_Unknown_in_other_constructs)

If a.keya is NULL, then a.keya != 'a' is `UNKNOWN`, then `a.keya not in ('a', 'b')` is `UNKNOWN`.

So your issue is, there's one or more NULL in **b.keyb**. So all `a.keya not in (select b.keyb from b)` result `UNKNOWN`. The result is 0.